# Regex match a specific string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to extract the string `<Num>` from within `Barcode(_<Num>_).PDF` using Regex. I am looking at [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it is not easy. Thanks for any help.

```
    Dim pattern As String = "^Barcode(_+_)\.pdf" 
    If Regex.IsMatch("Barcode(_abc123_).pdf", pattern) Then
        Debug.Print("match")
    End If
```

Comment: You need a `\d` before the `+` otherwise you are just matching underscores

Comment: What's an example file name look like? `Barcode_123_.pdf`? Or something else?

Comment: like `Barcode(_abc123_).pdf`; could be numbers or string; I want the `abc123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to not only match but also READ the value of  into a variable, then you will need to call the Regex.Match method instead of simply calling the boolean isMatch  method.  The Match method will return a Match object that will let you get to the groups and captures from your pattern.

Your pattern would need be something like `"Barcode\(_(.*)_\)\.pdf"`-- note the inner parenthesis which will create a capture group for you to obtain the value of the string between the underscores..  See [a MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for examples of almost exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't match yet; I will check out the website you mentioned

Comment: Actually it varies by language... I will edit my answer, I think using Vb.net you will want to escape the *real* parentheses, not the grouping ones.  ie "Barcode\(_(.*)_\)\.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the regex in VB, but I can offer you a website to examine the correctness of your  regex:   [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/).  In this case, if the `<Num>` is numbers, you can use "Barcode(_\d+_).pdf"

Comment: I tried your pattern with `"Barcode(_123_).pdf"` but it didn't match; I'll check out the Regex Tester

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tester; That's great!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is what I ended up using:

```
    'set up regex
    'I'm using + instead of * in the pattern to ensure that if no value is
    'present the match will fail
    Dim pattern As String = "Barcode\(_(.+)_\)\.pdf"
    Dim r As Regex = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    'get match
    Dim mat As Match
    mat = r.Match("Barcode(_abc123_).pdf")

    'output the matched string
    If mat.Success Then
        Dim g As Group = mat.Groups(1)
        Dim cc As CaptureCollection = g.Captures
        Dim c As Capture = cc(0)
        Debug.Print(c.ToString)
    End If
```

[.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)